# Cloud9: Share a workspace with academic purposes

Tags: workspace, cloud9-ide

I have a blog called [Rails Karate](http://railskarate.com/en), I create free courses about web development stuff, I would like to share workspaces with my students so they can reproduce what I do, or follow my steps easier.

I create a workspace with everything set up. So a student can copy it, or clone it and start follow the steps of the lesson

For example [treehouse](http://treehouse.com) has something very similar, you start the lesson and can start a workspace with everything set up for follow the steps. I would like to know if I can make an approach of that with cloud9, Thanks!

Comment: Why not store checkpoint repositories in Github or Bitbucket?  Then, your students could start with the appropriate checkpoint into Cloud9 and begin work there.  More information [here](https://docs.c9.io/docs/setting-up-github-workspace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning workspaces themselves is not a feature as of the time of this post. As mentioned, you may teach them some Git then have them create a workspace from a repo and checkout different steps in there. More info on [sharing workspaces](https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/share-a-workspace).